# No change in editing wordpress style.css file of theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I went to

> Administration > Appearance > Editor

to edit the style.css .I edited it and updated, it showed a message that the file has been successfully edited but still there is no change.

I cleared cache and reloaded the site but still not change. What should I do ?

The Theme I'm trying to edit is [Catch KAthmandu](http://catchthemes.com/demo/catch-kathmandu/) and I just wanted to edit the color when cursor hover over the menu option i.e. "Home" "about us" n all

Comment: You might be using the same `class / id` name. Try adding `!important` at the end of each properties.

Comment: Also make sure that you, meanwhile, have not changed the theme this file belongs to or you are not using some sort of the caching plugin (like Easy cache, W3 Total cache, etc).

Comment: @rajmathan  I added !important at the end Still no change

Comment: @bodi0 not using any caching plugin

Comment: Menu items are very often tricky in CSS. There will be typically be a large number of styles that apply to menus and you may not style the right one at first pass. Open your inspector (In Chrome, right click and inspect element; in Firefox, same thing) and look at which rules are applying to your menu. Is the element you styled not showing your new style settings? Or is it simply not factoring in at all, or being overwritten by something else?

Comment: I would prefer evanv suggestion. Don't add styles before testing it in browser. I mean add your styles with your new class name in firebug/ crome developer tool. If changes happens then add it to your style sheet.